# How can I Encode a pink noise signal to spikes with snntorch.spikegen.latency?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have 2 pink noise signals created with a random generator
and I put that into a for-loop like:

```
for i in range(1000):
    input[i] = numpy.random.uniform(-1,1)
for i in range(1000):
    z[i] = z[i-1] + (1-b)*(z[i] - input[i-1])
```

Now I try to convert this via the snntorch library. I already used the rate coding part of this library and want to compare it with the latency coding part. So I want to use snntorch.spikegen.latency() but I don't know how to use it right. I changed all the parameters and got no good result.
Do you have any tips for the Encoding/Decoding part to convert this noise into a spike train and convert it back?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share how you're currently trying to use the `latency()` function?

It should be similar to `rate()` in that you just pass `z` to the latency function. Though there are many more options involved (e.g., `normalize=True` finds the time constant to ensure all spike times occur within the range of time `num_steps`).

Each element in `z` will correspond to one spike. So if it is of dimension `N`, then the output should be `T x N`.

The value/intensity of the element corresponds to what time that spike occurs. Negative intensities don't make sense here, so either take the absolute value of `z` before passing it in, or level shift it.